# Asterisk AMI Originating works but hangs up

Tags: asteriskami

Asterisk 1.6? on Ipitomy IP5000.

I can connected to the AMI just fine.  I can issue:

```
Action: Originate
Channel: sip/122
Exten: 5556666 (i use my own cell number here)
Context: default
Priority: 1
Timeout: 30000
```

This causes my desk phone to ring, when I answer the system hangs up. The call isn't connected to my cell number.

I have also tried the above with:

```
Context: from-internal
```

and

```
Async: True
```

All have the same result. I'm also fairly sure that it is Asterisk 1.6 because Action: ListCommands shows commands that weren't available until 1.6

Answer (score 0):

The answer was the Context: I used Action: Status to see what outgoing calls looked like on this system. Noted Priority and Context then tried these inside my PHP script. Bang, it placed the call like i wanted.

I cannot however get it to set a CallerID name even using Callerid: "Test" 5555555555 (this is an example as I'm suing the real numbers)

Comment: Because i didn't find any documentation actually giving an example, asterisk ami callerid is set like this Callerid: "Name <5555555555>"   It does need the brackets on each side. Hope this helps someone.